# How to Output an structured Category Treen in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm

I faced following challenge. I got a db table with 3 columns. There are all the store categories of a onlineshop. So the first column is the id of the category, the second row is the name of the category and the third is the supercategory of this one ore in other words, it's the category which this one is the subcategory of. If in the third row is an 0 that means that this category has no supöercategorys.

```
 id     |    name    |    supercategory 
 ----------------------------------------
    1   |   Outdoor  |      0
----------------------------------------
    2   |   Home     |      0
----------------------------------------
    3   |   Camping  |      1
----------------------------------------
    4   |   Car      |      2
----------------------------------------
    5   |   Garden   |      1
----------------------------------------
```

So for example "Camping" would be a subcategory from Outdoor. So they can be up to 5 levels.

So my goal is it to analyse the database and output and Structure **Category tree** that readable for humans. 
Anyone can design and Algorithmus for that in PHP? I am Struggling hard with the logic of the Script which should perform that.

Preferable in and ul and li format. But the different levels could also be differentiate by h1, h2 , h3 and so on.

Comment: check this https://phptechnologytutorials.wordpress.com/2014/12/14/recursive-category-tree-in-php-and-mysql/

Comment: big Thanks to you. Simple but wery effective code snippet ;)